# How to get HTTP status code from WinHttp request?

Tags: winhttp

[This page on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains definitions of HTTP status codes presumably used in WinHTTP. Is there a way to retrieve HTTP status code from request made in WinHttp?

The only way I've found to get to response text, is to call `WinHttpQueryHeaders`, which returns HTTP response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 08:20:29 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Do I have to parse this string by myself to get status code, or is there some way already provided by WinHttp to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this to read http status code (hRequest - handle of the request).

```cpp
DWORD dwStatusCode = 0;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(dwStatusCode);

WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, 
    WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, 
    WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, 
    &dwStatusCode, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
```